# Get one child value attribute from <div> parent using click function in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

As pictures below I have a tone of img data in one parent div. I would like to return one model value when I click one of those icon in this map layout. What i have done it return all model value when I click those icon.

[image: GUI]
[image: GUI data]

here is my code

```
 $('#droparea img').click(function (e) {
     var imgs = $('#droparea').children('img').map(function () {
         var modelid = $(this).attr('model');                   
         console.log(modelid);
     }
 });
```

How to get one value when I click one of those icon?

Comment: `$(this).attr('model')` ? On click of the `img`, you can directly execute this code.

Comment: yess correct it can directly execute his code ..but it return all image data..but i just want to return image data that has been clicked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just do this?

```
$('#droparea img').click(function (e) {
    var modelid = $(this).attr('model');                   
    console.log(modelid);
});
```